# Rewriting a pl/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am looking to simplify a function I have to calculate the duration between two events. My database has three tables that are used in the function.

1. **EVENTS TABLE** - This table regroups all events. The events we are interested in are those with device_type 1 (= entry) and device_type 2 (= exit)
   [image]
2. **DURATIONS TABLE** - This is the table that is filled when the function runs. It will find the first two events with the same card nr and device type 1 and device type 2 in the events table, calculate the duration between the two events and save it in the duration table.
   [image]
3. **PROPERTIES** - This table is used as reference and will be updated and used for future inserts as well.

[image]

**DDL SCRIPTS**

```
   -- events
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events (
        id bigint NOT NULL autoincrement start 1 increment 1 PRIMARY KEY,
        odb_created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
        event_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
        device_type integer NOT NULL,
        event_type integer NOT NULL,
        ticket_type integer NOT NULL,
        card_nr character varying(100),
        count integer DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
        manufacturer character varying(200),
        carpark_id bigint
    ); 

     -- durations
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS durations (
        id bigint NOT NULL autoincrement start 1 increment 1 PRIMARY KEY,
        odb_created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
        event_id_arrival bigint,
        event_id_departure bigint,
        event_time_arrival timestamp without time zone,
        event_time_departure timestamp without time zone,
        card_nr character varying(100),
        ticket_type integer,
        duration integer,
        manufacturer character varying(200),
        carpark_id bigint
    );

    --properties
    create or replace TABLE PROPERTIES (
        PROP_KEY VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
        PROP_VALUE VARCHAR(250),
        primary key (PROP_KEY)
    );


INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188160996, '2021-10-02 04:28:26.338', '2021-10-01 09:14:41.32', 1, 2, 11, '03998988030897300007782', 1, 'XX', 1852);
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188160790, '2021-10-02 04:28:26.248', '2021-10-01 09:31:10.94', 2, 2, 11, '03998988030897300007782', 1, 'XX', 1852);
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188146489, '2021-10-02 04:26:55.069', '2021-10-01 10:03:01.57', 1, 2, 500, '01479804030429500089598', 1, 'XX', 1563);
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188146069, '2021-10-02 04:26:54.852', '2021-10-01 11:49:58.45', 2, 2, 500, '01479804030429500089598', 1, 'XX', 1563);
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188161161, '2021-10-02 04:28:26.372', '2021-10-01 18:44:33.62', 1, 2, 11, '03998988030897300007782', 1, 'XX', 1852);
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188160950, '2021-10-02 04:28:26.329', '2021-10-01 18:45:51.903', 2, 2, 11, '03998988030897300007782', 1, 'XX', 1852);
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188161227, '2021-10-02 04:28:26.374', '2021-10-01 23:21:18.58', 1, 2, 11, '04139733030897300003136', 1, 'XX', 1852);
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188160974, '2021-10-02 04:28:26.334', '2021-10-01 23:24:03.29', 2, 2, 11, '04139733030897300003136', 1, 'XX', 1852);
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188239864, '2021-10-03 04:24:43.345', '2021-10-02 06:49:55.97', 1, 2, 11, '01719400030897300061410', 1, 'XX', 1852);
INSERT INTO public.events (id, odb_created_at, event_time, device_type, event_type, ticket_type, card_nr, count, manufacturer, carpark_id) VALUES(188239649, '2021-10-03 04:24:43.308', '2021-10-02 07:02:08.72', 2, 2, 11, '01719400030897300061410', 1, 'XX', 1852);
```

Here's an exemple:

1. Events
   [image]
2. Function runs, inserts to durations
   [image]
3. Properties are updated

**Here's my function**

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.calculateduration()
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE

     arrived_entry RECORD;
     departed_entry RECORD;  

     durationLimitDays INTEGER := -1;
     durationLimitDate TIMESTAMP := '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
     
     cursorQuery text;
     cursorEvent refcursor;
     
     maxEventTime TIMESTAMP;
     
BEGIN

    -- start date   = DURATION.LIMIT.DATE
    -- end date     = now - DURATION.LIMIT.DAYS
    SELECT PROP_VALUE INTO durationLimitDays FROM properties WHERE prop_key = 'DURATION.LIMIT.DAYS';
    SELECT PROP_VALUE INTO durationLimitDate FROM properties WHERE prop_key = 'DURATION.LIMIT.DATE';
    RAISE NOTICE 'Parameter duration limit days ''%'' , duration limit date ''%''', durationLimitDays, durationLimitDate;
    
    --  AND e.event_time < to_char(now(), ''YYYY-MM-DD'')::date - (''42 month''::interval)
    cursorQuery:='SELECT e.id, e.card_nr, e.event_time, e.ticket_type, e.device_type, e.manufacturer, e.carpark_id
                  FROM events e 
                  WHERE e.event_time >= ''' || durationLimitDate || '''
                  AND e.device_type IN (1,2) AND event_type=2
                  AND e.manufacturer like ''DESIGNA_ABACUS%''
                  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT d.event_id_arrival FROM durations d WHERE d.event_id_arrival = e.id)
                  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT d.event_id_departure FROM durations d WHERE d.event_id_departure = e.id)
                  ORDER BY e.card_nr, e.event_time, e.carpark_id';
                  -- AND e.event_time < ''2016-01-05 00:00:00'' 
    OPEN cursorEvent SCROLL FOR EXECUTE cursorQuery;

    LOOP
        FETCH cursorEvent INTO arrived_entry;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
        IF arrived_entry.device_type=1 THEN
            FETCH cursorEvent INTO departed_entry;
            EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
            
            -- same card number and same car park
            IF arrived_entry.card_nr=departed_entry.card_nr AND arrived_entry.carpark_id=departed_entry.carpark_id THEN
                IF departed_entry.device_type=2 THEN
                    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO durations VALUES (nextval(''durations_id_seq''), ''' || current_timestamp || ''',' || arrived_entry.id || ',' || departed_entry.id || ',''' || arrived_entry.event_time || ''',''' || departed_entry.event_time 
                                                              || ''',''' || arrived_entry.card_nr || ''',' || arrived_entry.ticket_type || ',' 
                                                              || date_part('epoch', departed_entry.event_time::timestamp - arrived_entry.event_time::timestamp) || ', ''' || arrived_entry.manufacturer || ''',' 
                                                              || arrived_entry.carpark_id || ')';
                ELSE 
                    -- repeated entry found - refresh entry with the repeated one 
                    -- RAISE NOTICE 'Unexpected entry after entry found at event id ''%'' and card number''%''', arrived_entry.id, arrived_entry.card_nr;
                    FETCH PRIOR FROM cursorEvent INTO arrived_entry;
                END IF;
            ELSE
                -- card number or car park changed - refresh to changed card number / car park
                -- RAISE NOTICE 'Unexpected card number or car park change found at event id ''%'' and card number''%''', arrived_entry.id, arrived_entry.card_nr;
                FETCH PRIOR FROM cursorEvent INTO arrived_entry;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursorEvent;
    
    -- update duration limit date ( = MAX(event_time) - durationLimitDays)
    EXECUTE 'SELECT MAX(event_time) FROM events WHERE event_time >= ''' || durationLimitDate || '''' INTO maxEventTime;
    SELECT (maxEventTime - (durationLimitDays ||' day')::interval) INTO durationLimitDate;
    EXECUTE 'UPDATE properties SET PROP_VALUE=''' || durationLimitDate || ''' WHERE prop_key =''DURATION.LIMIT.DATE''';
    RAISE NOTICE 'Add new DURATION.LIMIT.DATE to ''%''', durationLimitDate;
        
END;
$function$
;
```

How may I rewrite it in an easier way knowing that:

1. In our select, we should only calculate the durations where events.event_time >) durationLimitDate from properties
2. I need to make sure that the event_id_arrival and event_id_departure are not in the target table already to avoid duplicates
3. Once I inserted the calculations to the duration table, I must update the durationLimitDate in the properties. Knowing that `durationLimitDate = (Max(event_time) - durationLimitDays))`

---

**First try**

```
INSERT INTO durations (id, odb_created_at, event_id_arrival, event_id_departure, event_time_arrival, event_time_departure, card_nr, ticket_type, duration, manufacturer, carpark_id)

SELECT nextval('durations_id_seq'), 
       current_timestamp, 
       arrived_entry.id, 
       departed_entry.id, 
       arrived_entry.event_time,
       departed_entry.event_time,
       arrived_entry.card_nr, 
       arrived_entry.ticket_type, 
       date_part('epoch', departed_entry.event_time::timestamp - arrived_entry.event_time::timestamp), 
       arrived_entry.manufacturer, 
       arrived_entry.carpark_id

FROM (SELECT e.id, e.card_nr, e.event_time, e.ticket_type, e.manufacturer, e.carpark_id
      FROM events e 
      LEFT JOIN durations d ON d.event_id_arrival = e.id
      WHERE e.event_time >= TO_TIMESTAMP((SELECT PROP_VALUE FROM properties WHERE prop_key = 'DURATION.LIMIT.DATE'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS')
            AND e.device_type = 1
            AND event_type = 2
            AND e.manufacturer LIKE 'DESIGNA_ABACUS%'
            AND d.id IS NULL) AS arrived_entry
            
INNER JOIN (SELECT e.id, e.card_nr, e.carpark_id, e.event_time
            FROM events e 
            LEFT JOIN durations d ON d.event_id_departure = e.id
            WHERE e.event_time >= TO_TIMESTAMP((SELECT PROP_VALUE FROM properties WHERE prop_key = 'DURATION.LIMIT.DATE'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS')
                  AND e.device_type = 2 
                  AND event_type = 2
                  AND e.manufacturer LIKE 'DESIGNA_ABACUS%'
                  AND d.id IS NULL) AS departed_entry ON arrived_entry.card_nr = departed_entry.card_nr AND arrived_entry.carpark_id = departed_entry.carpark_id;
```

**Issues:**

1. event_id_arrival > many duplicates, up to 600. I need to make sure that the event_id_arrival and event_id_departure are not in the target table already to avoid duplicates
2. Once I inserted the calculations to the duration table, I must update the durationLimitDate in the properties. Knowing that durationLimitDate = (Max(event_time) - durationLimitDays))

Comment: Try to share tables structure as text, because we can't try the function without them. You should share some sample data too (`INSERT` statements).

Comment: @nachospiu I have modified the question and added all the ddls and some sample data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of iterating over the records you could write a query like the following to insert rows into `durations`:

Check the query because I couldn't try it, because you shared tables structure as images.

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT e.id, e.card_nr, e.event_time, e.ticket_type, e.manufacturer, e.carpark_id, e.device_type,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e.card_nr, e.carpark_id, e.event_time, e.device_type) AS rn
             FROM events e 
             LEFT JOIN durations d ON d.event_id_arrival = e.id OR d.event_id_departure = e.id
             WHERE e.event_time >= (SELECT PROP_VALUE::timestamp FROM properties WHERE prop_key = 'DURATION.LIMIT.DATE')
                   AND e.device_type IN (1, 2)
                   AND event_type = 2
                   AND e.manufacturer LIKE 'DESIGNA_ABACUS%'
                   AND d.id IS NULL
     ),
     
     arrived_entry AS (SELECT *
                       FROM cte
                       WHERE device_type = 1
     ),
     
     departed_entry AS (SELECT *
                       FROM cte
                       WHERE device_type = 2
     )
     
INSERT INTO durations (id, odb_created_at, event_id_arrival, event_id_departure, 
                       event_time_arrival, event_time_departure,
                       card_nr, ticket_type, duration, manufacturer, carpark_id)       
     
SELECT nextval('durations_id_seq'), 
       current_timestamp, 
       arrived_entry.id, 
       departed_entry.id, 
       arrived_entry.event_time, 
       departed_entry.event_time,
       arrived_entry.card_nr, 
       arrived_entry.ticket_type, 
       date_part('epoch', departed_entry.event_time::timestamp - arrived_entry.event_time::timestamp), 
       arrived_entry.manufacturer, 
       arrived_entry.carpark_id
FROM arrived_entry
INNER JOIN departed_entry ON arrived_entry.card_nr = departed_entry.card_nr 
                             AND arrived_entry.carpark_id = departed_entry.carpark_id
                             AND arrived_entry.rn + 1 = departed_entry.rn;
```

You can replace this query `(SELECT PROP_VALUE FROM properties WHERE prop_key = 'DURATION.LIMIT.DATE')` using the value of `durationLimitDate` variable.

**Pl/PgSQL function calculateduration():**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculateduration() RETURNS void AS $function$

DECLARE

     durationLimitDays INTEGER := -1;
     durationLimitDate TIMESTAMP := '1970-01-01 00:00:00';
     
BEGIN

    -- start date   = DURATION.LIMIT.DATE
    -- end date     = now - DURATION.LIMIT.DAYS
    SELECT PROP_VALUE INTO durationLimitDays FROM properties WHERE prop_key = 'DURATION.LIMIT.DAYS';
    SELECT PROP_VALUE::timestamp INTO durationLimitDate FROM properties WHERE prop_key = 'DURATION.LIMIT.DATE';
    RAISE NOTICE 'Parameter duration limit days ''%'' , duration limit date ''%''', durationLimitDays, durationLimitDate;
    
    WITH cte AS (SELECT e.id, e.card_nr, e.event_time, e.ticket_type, e.manufacturer, e.carpark_id, e.device_type,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e.card_nr, e.carpark_id, e.event_time, e.device_type) AS rn
             FROM events e 
             LEFT JOIN durations d ON d.event_id_arrival = e.id OR d.event_id_departure = e.id
             WHERE e.event_time >= durationLimitDate
                   AND e.device_type IN (1, 2)
                   AND event_type = 2
                   AND e.manufacturer LIKE 'DESIGNA_ABACUS%'
                   AND d.id IS NULL)
         
    INSERT INTO durations (id, odb_created_at, event_id_arrival, event_id_departure, 
                       event_time_arrival, event_time_departure,
                       card_nr, ticket_type, duration, manufacturer, carpark_id)       
         
    SELECT nextval('durations_id_seq'), 
           current_timestamp, 
           arrived_entry.id, 
           departed_entry.id, 
           arrived_entry.event_time, 
           departed_entry.event_time,
           arrived_entry.card_nr, 
           arrived_entry.ticket_type, 
           date_part('epoch', departed_entry.event_time::timestamp - arrived_entry.event_time::timestamp), 
           arrived_entry.manufacturer, 
           arrived_entry.carpark_id
    FROM (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE cte.device_type = 1) AS arrived_entry
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE cte.device_type = 2) AS departed_entry ON arrived_entry.card_nr = departed_entry.card_nr 
                                                                              AND arrived_entry.carpark_id = departed_entry.carpark_id
                                                                              AND arrived_entry.rn + 1 = departed_entry.rn;
    
    -- update duration limit date ( = MAX(event_time) - durationLimitDays)
    SELECT (MAX(event_time) - (durationLimitDays ||' day')::interval) INTO durationLimitDate FROM events WHERE event_time >= durationLimitDate;
    UPDATE properties SET PROP_VALUE = durationLimitDate WHERE PROP_KEY ='DURATION.LIMIT.DATE';
    RAISE NOTICE 'Add new DURATION.LIMIT.DATE to ''%''', durationLimitDate;
        
END;
$function$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**SQL function calculateduration():**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculateduration() RETURNS void AS $function$

    WITH cte AS (SELECT e.id, e.card_nr, e.event_time, e.ticket_type, e.manufacturer, e.carpark_id, e.device_type,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e.card_nr, e.carpark_id, e.event_time, e.device_type) AS rn
             FROM events e 
             LEFT JOIN durations d ON d.event_id_arrival = e.id OR d.event_id_departure = e.id
             WHERE e.event_time >= (SELECT PROP_VALUE::timestamp FROM properties WHERE prop_key = 'DURATION.LIMIT.DATE')
                   AND e.device_type IN (1, 2)
                   AND event_type = 2
                   AND e.manufacturer LIKE 'DESIGNA_ABACUS%'
                   AND d.id IS NULL)
         
    INSERT INTO durations (id, odb_created_at, event_id_arrival, event_id_departure, 
                       event_time_arrival, event_time_departure,
                       card_nr, ticket_type, duration, manufacturer, carpark_id)       
         
    SELECT nextval('durations_id_seq'), 
           current_timestamp, 
           arrived_entry.id, 
           departed_entry.id, 
           arrived_entry.event_time, 
           departed_entry.event_time,
           arrived_entry.card_nr, 
           arrived_entry.ticket_type, 
           date_part('epoch', departed_entry.event_time::timestamp - arrived_entry.event_time::timestamp), 
           arrived_entry.manufacturer, 
           arrived_entry.carpark_id
    FROM (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE cte.device_type = 1) AS arrived_entry
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE cte.device_type = 2) AS departed_entry ON arrived_entry.card_nr = departed_entry.card_nr 
                                                                              AND arrived_entry.carpark_id = departed_entry.carpark_id
                                                                              AND arrived_entry.rn + 1 = departed_entry.rn;
    
    UPDATE properties 
    SET PROP_VALUE = (SELECT (MAX(event_time) - ((SELECT PROP_VALUE FROM properties WHERE prop_key = 'DURATION.LIMIT.DAYS') ||' day')::interval) FROM events WHERE event_time >= (SELECT PROP_VALUE::timestamp FROM properties WHERE prop_key = 'DURATION.LIMIT.DATE')) 
    WHERE PROP_KEY ='DURATION.LIMIT.DATE';

$function$

LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: Hey @nachospiu, thank you. I just tried it. With your query, the output is 36767 rows with an event table having 10k rows only.. There are a lot of duplicates event_id_arrivals for instance... With the function, the output is 1599 rows with that same event table. I have added the query with some of my changes and the issues we have in my question on the top of the page. Thanks again!

Comment: You are right @Djabone! because you have several rows with the same `card_nr` and `carpark_id` in the same day. I didn't realize that you only take into account the consecutive (one with `device_type` = 1 and the other with `device_type` = 2). I updated my query, let me know if it is better.

Comment: Hey @nachospiu! We're getting closer. There are no duplicate ids anymore. To resume, with my function, the output is: 1599 rows. With your query I get 1629 rows in the first run - the strange part is that if I rerun the query, more data is imported. Went from 1629 to 1647 on the second run and 1662 on the third run. There should be no more inserts after the first run since no new data has been imported to the events. Nevertheless it's a huge step, and if we manage to also implement .2) with the update of properties, it would be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Djabone! I updated my query because I missed to check if the `event_id_departure` exist on `durations` table. I understand that if you make the insert, the second run have to return 0 rows, I try it with the sample data and this is the result I got. If the amount of record is different, You should find this records to understand what is happening. You can replace this query in your functions (take of the loop) and use the update properties query on your function. This query should be faster than iterate over a cursor.

Comment: Seems like it fixed the issue! :) To be honest I'm completely lost in the way I would be able to implement this in the function? Getting rid of the loop and replacing the query should have done the trick?

Comment: I rewrite the function, try it an let me know if it is ok.

Comment: That should not be possible since the data is imported once a day via an ETL Job. So the data is always imported at 4 am every day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238361/discussion-between-nachospiu-and-djabone).